# Getting fat arrow behaviour when passing function references

Tags: ecmascript-6

If I'm passing a function in ES6:

```
methodAcceptsFunction(this.myFunction);
```

...is there a way in ES6 to avoid having to call `.bind()` on it similar to the fat arrow behaviour?

```
methodAcceptsFunction(() => { this.myFunction(); });
```

In the first case, `this` is bound to the function.  But in the second, `this` is more in line with class-style programming.

Comment: There is a [proposal for a "bind" operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator) `methodAcceptsFunction(this::myFunction)` but it's not in ES6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way in ES6 to avoid having to call `.bind()` on it similar to the fat arrow behaviour?

No there is not.

> similar to the fat arrow behaviour

The way arrow functions work is that their environment simply doesn't have a `this` value, so `this` is looked up in the parent environment.

It is not possible to modify the characteristics of a function environment of an existing function.